# I can't read the value from the sql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I send query to database and i get response in TextRow object and i cannot read value always is undefined. I want to read from the database the password that is assigned to the email so that the user can log in. All console logs return undefined

```
    const db = require('../db/mysql');
    router.post("/login", (req, res, next)=>{
    let email = req.body.email;
    db.query("SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = ?", [email]).then(function (result) {
        if(result[0].password == req.body.password) {
            console.log(result[0].password);
            res.redirect("/users");
        }else{
            console.log(result[0].password);
            return false;
        }
    });
    // Example from documenation also send undefined value
    db.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = 'aaa@wp.pl;", function (err, result, fields) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(fields);
    })
});
```

And here is db connection class

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'admin',
    database: 'weekop',
    multipleStatements: true,
    charset: 'utf8'
});

module.exports = pool.promise();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the promise() call to mysql2, not the callback version.

The correct example should be (from https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2):

```
con.promise().query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = 'aaa@wp.pl;")
  .then(([rows, fields]) => {
      console.log(rows);
      console.log(fields);
  })
  .catch(console.log)
  .then( () => con.end());
```